# Native messaging host in Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

The new Microsoft Edge program is now open to accept chromium-based extensions for the new Microsoft Edge (ver. 77 or above). I have tested my chrome extension on Edge browser and it gets installed in Edge browser. I am trying to reuse the native host in Edge browser which is developed for Chrome browser. But somehow it is not working.

Does anyone has any idea about how to support the chrome native host in Edge browser? or do I need to implement the native host by using UWP?

I have tried communicationg with native host from my edge extension but getting the "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Specified native messaging host not found." Error.
code from .js file

```
var hostname = "com.microsoft.edge.myExtension";
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostname);
```

Manifest(com.microsoft.edge.myExtension.json) file for my native host

```
    "name": "com.microsoft.edge.myExtension",
    "description": "My Native Host",
    "path": "C:\\EdgeNativeHost.exe",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
        "extension://pbdancjikoidhjcgkfpipggnhlackjpe/"
    ]
}
```

Added registry key by running shell command

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Edge\NativeMessagingHosts\com.microsoft.edge.myExtension" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\com.microsoft.edge.myExtension.json" /f
```

Please let me know what's the wrong with me?

Answer (score 1):

Extensions written for Chromium, in most cases, run on Microsoft (Chromium) Edge with minimal changes. You could refer to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/port-chrome-extension) about how to port a Chrome Extension to Microsoft (Chromium) Edge.

You should check if you have used the following extension APIs which are not supported by Microsoft Edge:

> The extension APIs and manifest keys supported by Chrome are code-compatible with Microsoft (Chromium) Edge. However, Microsoft Edge does not support the following Extension APIs:
>
> - `chrome.gcm`
> - `chrome.identity.getAccounts`
> - `chrome.identity.getAuthToken`
> - `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo`
> - `chrome.instanceID`

You should also re-brand the Extension for `Microsoft Edge` if you are using `Chrome` in the name or description of your Extension.

**For native messaging host, you should especially note:**

> If your Extension exchanges messages with a native application using `chrome.runtime.connectNative` API, ensure that you set `allowedorigins` to "`extension://[Microsoft-Catalog-extensionID]`" in your native messaging host manifest file. This enables the app to identify the Extension.

For more information, you could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/native-messaging). The native messaging host location is also a little different from Chrome Extension. `Google\Chrome` in the registry key should be `Microsoft\Edge`.

Comment: I have tried mentioned steps from the article but the native host is not getting launched.

Comment: Have you debugged the extension with the [developer features turned on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/getting-started/part1-simple-extension#run-your-extension-locally-in-your-browser-while-developing-it-side-loading)? You can debug your extension using DevTools. Is there any error you get when debugging? Besides, could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help?

Comment: I have edited my question and added some code. Please let me know where is the issue

Comment: I reproduced the issue with editing the official demo of Google Chrome native messaging. I'll discuss with other senior engineers. I'll let you know if I have any updates.

Comment: Hi @YuZhou, am trying to buid similar solution to open ms excel application and push some message form extension to ms-excel, so that ms-excel add-in to read the message and do some operation. But not able to figure out a way on how to push message to ms excel application. any light on this approach is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sam,

According to the information you provided us, there is an issue in your registry configuration.

Note, that if your using "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", the path has "Microsoft" in it instead of "Google"

Otherwise, you can use "HKEY_CURRENT_USER", in where the path has "Google" in it instead of "Microsoft."

Lastly, your key must have its default value set to the path of your native-message-host manifest.json file.

See below explanation from [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/native-messaging)

> On Windows, the manifest file may be located anywhere in the file
> system. The application installer must create registry key
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ **Microsoft\Edge** \NativeMessagingHosts\com.my_company.my_application
>
> or
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ **Google\Chrome** \NativeMessagingHosts\com.my_company.my_application

Also mind you that there are some other requirements before it will work like setting the origin to your extensions's and that your manifest must have the 'path' value set to your native-message-host executable.

Comment: Hi @RashadRivera  , am trying to buid similar solution to open ms excel application and push some message form extension to ms-excel, so that ms-excel add-in to read the message and do some operation. But not able to figure out a way on how to push message to ms excel application. any light on this approach is highly appreciated